# asterisk 11.6 "core show channels" output

Tags: asterisk, telephony, telecommunication

In asterisk 11.6, if we execute the command "core show channels" we are getting the following output.

```
DAHDI/i<span>/callerid-sequence_number
```

But I want the output like the below format ( older version )

```
DAHDI/<channel_Number>-<span>
```

I am upgrading the asterisk version from 1.6 to 11.6 . What changes I need to do in the configuration or source code to get the output like older version in 11.6?

Answer (score 0):

You can't easy change source code. That affect multiple places, rewrite is very complex.

You have change your program. Or rewrite output of core show channels before your program(using programs like ami proxy)